# Why nmi_enter() when there is no NMI ( only machine check exception )?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

https://gitlab.com/redhat/centos-stream/src/kernel/centos-stream-8/-/blob/c8s/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mce/core.c#L1299

```
void noinstr do_machine_check(struct pt_regs *regs, long error_code)
{
...
nmi_enter();
...
```

In my understanding, this `nmi_enter()` means to enter NMI context but if there is no NMI ( only machine check exception ) why need to enter NMI context?

P.S This is CentOS/Redhat kernel code, not upstream kernel code.